# Eu não consigo compilar meu programa pois, estou com um erro que diz "NullPointerException"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando montar um projeto em Java segundo os conceitos de programação orientada objetos.

No entanto o compilador(ECLIPSE) acusa um erro na linha da minha função liigar. Ele diz que tem um erro de NullPointerException. Pesquisando na internet vi que isso é quando a variável é "não inicialiazada". Chequei meu programa e tenho um valor default que eu coloco para a varável como um "false". Gostaria de poder entender porque o eclipse está acusando este erro.

Nesta classe eu coloquei a main:

```
public class TestaCarro {   

public static void main(String[] args){

    Carro meuCarro = new Carro();

        meuCarro.setCor("Azul");

        meuCarro.setModelo("Gol");
        // ligando o carro
        meuCarro.ligar();
        // Acelerando o carro
        meuCarro.acelerar(80);
        // Obtendo a marcha atual
        int marchaAtual = meuCarro.obtemMarcha();

        // Imprimindo informações sobre o carro e o estado dos atributos
        System.out.print("Meu " + meuCarro.getModelo() + " " + meuCarro.getCor() + " ");
        System.out.print("Está andando na marcha " + marchaAtual + " a ");
        System.out.print(meuCarro.getVelocidadeAtual() + " Km/h!!!");

        // Parando o carro
        meuCarro.parar();

        // Acelerando o carro novamente
        meuCarro.acelerar(20);
        // Obtendo a marcha atual novmente
        marchaAtual = meuCarro.obtemMarcha();

        // Imprimindo(novamente) informações sobre o carr e o estado dos atributos
        System.out.print("Agora, meu " + meuCarro.getModelo() + " " + meuCarro.getCor() + " ");
        System.out.print(" está andando na marcha " + marchaAtual + " a ");
        System.out.println(meuCarro.getVelocidadeAtual() + " Km/h!!!");

        // Parando o carro
        meuCarro.parar();

        // Desligando o carro
        meuCarro.desligar();
    }
}
```

Nesta classe tenho a primeira função ligar:

```
public class Carro {
    private String cor, modelo;// get e set
    private int velocidadeAtual;// Apenas get
    private double velocidadeMaxima = 140;// Definido por default + get
    private Motor motor; // get e set

    // Método para ligar o carro
    public void ligar() {
        if (this.motor.ligar())
            System.out.println("O carro está sendo ligado...");
    }

    // Método para parar o carro
    public void parar() {
        System.out.println("Parando o carro...");
        this.velocidadeAtual = 0;
    }

    // Método para desligar o carro
    public void desligar() {
        if (this.motor.desligar()) {
            System.out.println("O carro está sendo desligado...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Não há como desligar um carro em movimento.");
        }
    }

    // Métodos get, set, acelerar, obterMarcha...
    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public Motor getMotor() {
        return motor;
    }

    public void setMotor(Motor motor) {
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public double getVelocidadeAtual() {
        return velocidadeAtual;
    }

    public double getVelocidadeMaxima() {
        return velocidadeMaxima;
    }
    //Método qued devolve a marcha em que o carro está.
    public void acelerar(double velocidade){
        this.velocidadeAtual+=velocidade;
    }
// Método que devolve a marcha em que o carro está

        public int obtemMarcha() {

         if(this.velocidadeAtual<=0) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
              if(this.velocidadeAtual<=20) {
                return 1;
        }
        else {
              if(this.velocidadeAtual<=40) {
                return 2;
            }
            else {
                  if(this.velocidadeAtual<=60) {
                    return 3;
                }
                else {
                      if(this.velocidadeAtual<=80) {
                            return 4;
                        }
                         else {
                            return 5;
                         }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Agora eu inicializo nesta outra class a função ligar:

```
public class Motor {

    private double potencia;// get e set
    private String tipoDeCombustivel;// get set
    private boolean ligado = false;// is e set

    public boolean ligar() {
        this.ligado = true;
        System.out.println("Ligando o motor...");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean desligar() {
        this.ligado = false;
        System.out.println("Desligando o motor..");
        return true;
    }

    public double getPotencia() {
        return potencia;
    }

    public void setPotencia(double potencia) {
        this.potencia = potencia;
    }

    public String getTipoDeCombustivel() {
        return tipoDeCombustivel;
    }

    public void setTipoDeCombustivel(String tipoDeCombustivel) {
        this.tipoDeCombustivel = tipoDeCombustivel;
    }

    public boolean isLigado() {
        return ligado;
    }

    public void setLigado(boolean ligado) {
        this.ligado = ligado;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está dando erro de `NullPointer` no método `ligar` e este encontra-se na classe `Motor`, o mais provável é que você não criou um objeto de `Motor`.

Na sua classe `Carro` tem uma variável do tipo `Motor`, certo? Chamar um método da classe motor causa erro de `NullPointer` porque ela é apenas uma variável, e não um objeto.

Faça o seguinte, dentro do seu construtor da classe `Carro`, instancie o objeto `Motor` da seguinte forma:

```
motor = new Motor();
```

Agora `motor` é um objeto e será possível chamar os métodos que ele possui.